# SQL Server create view with union

Tags: sql-server

I need to create one view, in the query I use union instruction but SQL Server shows an error about this.

This is the query:

```
select 
    co.number, co.dateCo, co.value, 
    cl.id, cl.name, cl.lastname, 
    sl.id, sl.name, sl.lastname, 
    cd.id, cd.name, 
    d.lastname, '0000' CompanyID, '' CompanyName, 
from 
    contrat co 
inner join 
    customer cl on co.constumer = cl.id
inner join 
    Seller sl on co.seller = sl.id
inner join 
    collector cd on co.collector = cd.id

union

select 
    co.number, co.dateCo, co.value, 
    cl.id, cl.name, cl.lastname, 
    sl.id, sl.name, sl.lastname, 
    cd.id, cd.name, 
    d.lastname, cp.id CompanyID, cp.name CompanyName, 
from 
    contrat co 
inner join 
    customer cl on co.constumer = cl.id
inner join 
    Seller sl on co.seller = sl.id
inner join 
    collector cd on co.collector = cd.id
inner join 
    Company cp on co.company = co.id
```

Comment: In general, if you're posting a question concerning an error, you should also post the error that you're receiving.

Comment: You also might want to consider UNION ALL vs Union, it is faster if you are not trying to eliminate duplicates

Comment: First of all, both your column lists end in an unneeded comma `,` just before the `from` - remove that. In your second `select`, the last join condition seems wrong: `Company cp on co.company = co.id` - shouldn't one of the two columns be from the `cp` table??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have extra comma before your `from` clause. The right statement would look like following.

```
select co.number, co.dateCo, co.value, cl.id, cl.name, cl.lastname, sl.id,    
  sl.name, sl.lastname, cd.id, cd.name, d.lastname, '0000' CompanyID, '' 
  CompanyName 
from contrat co inner join customer cl on co.constumer=cl.id
inner join Seller sl on co.seller=sl.id
inner join collector cd on co.collector=cd.id
union
select co.number, co.dateCo, co.value, cl.id, cl.name, cl.lastname, sl.id, 
  sl.name, sl.lastname, cd.id, cd.name, d.lastname, cp.id CompanyID, cp.name 
  CompanyName 
from contrat co inner join customer cl on co.constumer=cl.id
inner join Seller sl on co.seller=sl.id
inner join collector cd on co.collector=cd.id
inner join Company cp on co.company=co.id
```